# Does Firebase impacts performance of the Production App

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, crashlytics, firebase-analytics, firebase-performance

Does implementing Firebase SDKs and plugins impact the performance of an Android app?

I need to ship a production-ready Android app to Play Store. For analytics and continuous improvement purpose, I have implemented Firebase Crashlytics, Analytics, and Performance SDK into my app.

However, while monitoring the logs, I found that it continuously sends data over the network.

PSB sample log:

```
D/TransportRuntime.CctTransportBackend: Making request to: https://firebaselogging-pa.googleapis.com/v1/firelog/legacy/batchlog
```

My concerns are:

1. What will happen to a user with poor network connectivity?
2. Will Firebase impacts their already slow network. ?
3. Is it a good practice to ship Firebase into the Production app?

Please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does implementing Firebase SDKs and plugins impact the performance of an Android app?

It shouldn't. However, without seeing your code, it's impossible to say what might impact the performance.

> I need to ship a production-ready Android app to the Play Store.

That's why Firebase services are here for.

> What will happen to a user with poor network connectivity?

If a user has poor network connectivity and cannot reach Firebase servers, or if it has no connectivity at all, then it will fall on the cached version of the database. This will happen only if you have enabled **offline persistence** in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities) or in [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline). The latter is enabled by default in Android and iOs.

> Will Firebase impact their already slow network?

No. But the network will impact. If there is a healthy network connection, the performance impact in the case of the Realtime Database might come from the volume of data you download, and in the case of Cloud Firestore, it will depend [on the number of documents that are returned by your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212547/does-query-size-affect-firestore-snapshot-listeners-performance).

> Is it a good practice to ship Firebase into the Production app?

Definitely is. There are so many apps out there that are using Firebase.

Regarding the other Firebase services, it shouldn't impact the performance.